# Prisma [NextJS]: Many-to-many query is very slow

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js, prisma, entity-attribute-value

I have a nextJS project and I am using **Prisma** as an ORM.

The concerning database-tables look like this:

```
model cars_archive {
  id               Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  ...
  inactivestamp    DateTime? @db.DateTime(0)

  @@index([brand], map: "brand")
  @@index([model], map: "model")
}

model extras {
  id          Int           @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.MediumInt
  value       String        @unique(map: "value") @db.VarChar(255)
  extras_cars extras_cars[]
}

model extras_cars {
  car_id   Int
  extra_id Int    @db.MediumInt
  extras   extras @relation(fields: [extra_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "extras_cars_ibfk_1")
  cars     cars   @relation(fields: [car_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "extras_cars_ibfk_2")

  @@id([car_id, extra_id])
  @@index([car_id, extra_id], map: "car_id")
  @@index([extra_id], map: "extra_id")
}
```

I need a query that fetches all cars that have certain extras. Something like this:
`['Cruise Control', 'ABS',...]`

To do that I created the following query-statement:

```
const cars = await prisma.cars.findMany({
        where: {
            extras_cars: {
                every: {
                    extras: {
                        value: {
                            in: ['Cruise Control','ABS']
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

The thing is the query yields the desired result, but takes forever to return the list of cars (15 - 20 seconds).

I have tried the same thing with a simple SQL-Query which looks like this:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars JOIN extras_cars ec on cars.id = ec.car_id JOIN extras e on e.id = ec.extra_id WHERE e.value='Cruise Control'`
This query just takes about 1 second.

When looking at the debug-logs from Prisma it shows a really long SQL-query like this, which just doesn't make any sense to me:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT` carsDB`.`cars`.`id`FROM`carsDB`.`cars `WHERE (`carsDB`.`cars`.`id`) NOT IN (SELECT` t0`.`id`FROM`carsDB`.`cars`AS`t0`INNER JOIN`carsDB`.`extras_cars`AS`j0 `ON (`j0`.`car_id`) = (`t0`.`id`) WHERE ((NOT (`j0`.`car_id`,`j0`.`extra_id`) IN (SELECT` t1`.`car_id`,` t1`.`extra_id`FROM`carsDB`.`extras_cars`AS`t1`INNER JOIN`carsDB`.`extras`AS`j1 `ON (`j1`.`id`) = (`t1`.`extra_id`) WHERE (`j1`.`value`= ? AND`t1`.`car_id`IS NOT NULL AND`t1`.`extra_id`IS NOT NULL))) AND`t0`.`id`IS NOT NULL)) /* traceparent=00-00-00-00 */) AS`sub `/* traceparent=00-00-00-00 */`

Has somebody ever had a similar issue or has an idea of how to speed up the query?

The [documentation of Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries) doesn't yield any useful information.

BTW: My database is a mariadb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Performance of EAV schemas is really bad.  Follow the tag for suggestions.

Comment: Can you please enable debugging for queries in your Prisma Client [see docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/debugging) and post the full log you are getting? Maybe also just transfer this into a bug report issue and include all the information it asks for - the [bug report template](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.yml) helps us to have all the information.